# Changing jobs before 2 years as a Blue Card holder

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have been working in Germany for 1.5 year as a software engineer with my blue card.

The company's name **is not written** on the blue card, or on the extra paper that came with the card: written on it **„Beschäftigung gemäß § 18b Abs. 2 S. 1 AufenthG erlaubt“**

I got a new contract now from another company in the Germany. But I do not know if I can change jobs directly or if i need to do something as this information is confusing https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/en/ **specially the Fact sheet for foreign workers**.

I got told from some people that it should be possible somehow to send an email with the new contract since it's the same job title, and higher salary, but I have no idea about the process or the email.

How does that work? Any help would be appreciated.